# Delete user score as an App Admin with Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

Is there a way of deleting a specific user [Score](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/) from the Graph API Explorer?

Suppose there was a problem with the game and some users got wrong scores. Is there a way (assuming I'm the app admin) to fix that? to remove those scores?

Of course, using the Graph API Explorer or some other tool. I tried and it seems I can't access score information for any other user but myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete a user's score by issuing HTTP DELETE request to `/USER_ID/scores` with that user's access token or the App access token.

See more in the [Scores documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/) under the heading **Managing Scores for a user**

Comment: I've already tried that, without luck.

I clicked on "Get Access Token" to generate the token (which I'm not sure if it's the app token or my own). Then I tried what you said and I get an OAuthException: "(#240) Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user."

I'm using the correct user id, becuase if I query its name it works.

Comment: Seems to be solved.
In case someone else need to know, I generated the correct token using the Access Token tool.